# Explanation for "Scoller runner", it spams into the LogCat

Tags: android, logcat, nexus-4

I have a question about a Android task (?): The scoller run.

What is this?

Sometimes (it looks like a bug) the scoller run repeats its work endlessly and spames thousands of thousand of lines of code into the LogCat output.

The Code looks like:

```
11-19 16:50:02.657: V/scoller run(21557): scollerscoller
11-19 16:50:02.657: V/0(21557): 768
11-19 16:50:02.657: V/scoller run(21557): scollerscoller
11-19 16:50:02.657: V/0(21557): 768
11-19 16:50:02.657: V/scoller run(21557): scollerscoller
11-19 16:50:02.657: V/0(21557): 768
11-19 16:50:02.657: V/scoller run(21557): scollerscoller
11-19 16:50:02.657: V/0(21557): 768
11-19 16:50:02.657: V/scoller run(21557): scollerscoller
[...]
11-19 16:50:02.667: V/0(21557): 768
11-19 16:50:02.667: V/scoller run(21557): scollerscoller
11-19 16:50:02.667: V/0(21557): 768
11-19 16:50:02.667: V/scoller run(21557): scollerscoller
11-19 16:50:02.667: V/0(21557): 768
11-19 16:50:02.667: V/Customized(21557): 374...374...0
```

I can only stop this spam if I restart my device. My device is a Nexus 4 (not rooted).

Does anybody know what could be cause this issue?

Comment: same problem - after restarting the nexus 4 it disappears...